# setting style after getting highest column and Row

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

Is it possible to set style of each row dynamically after getting the highest column and highest Row ?

I tried

```
$highCol = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestDataColumn();
$highRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestDataRow();
$val ="'A6:" . $highCol .$highRow . "'";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($val)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

My PHP CGI crashes.

Comment: Hi, you'll need to give us a lot more context here. Highest column/row of what? do you have a database? maybe you could show us a representative example of data and what you expect to see as the values you get. Can you also show us the research you've done? you've googled for this right? why were the results unsatisfactory to you? anything else you've tried? When your CGI crashed - did it give an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A major problem is the spurious quotes in your `$val` variable

Try changing

```
$val ="'A6:" . $highCol .$highRow . "'";
```

to

```
$val ="A6:" . $highCol .$highRow;
```